# How to save photo from Telegram Bot (Aiogram) to PostgreSQL database?

Tags: python, postgresql, telegram, psycopg2

I use this to download photo:

```
file_info = await bot.get_file(photo[len(photo) - 1].file_id)
new_photo = await bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
```

and then `new_photo` is `_io.BytesIO` but i want to save it to PostgreSQL DB into `bytea` field and I have this error: `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type '_io.BytesIO'`.
I cannot convert to `bytes` this variable. How to save it to my DB? I googled but no result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had to convert this to `bytes` with `read()`:

```
file_info = await bot.get_file(photo[len(photo) - 1].file_id)
new_photo = (await bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)).read()
```