# cannot save a file to the postgres using psycopg2.Binary()

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, aiogram

I'm writing a tg bot. I need to save user's photo to the database. I use this code:

```
def parse_photo(file_path: str):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(f"https://api.telegram.org/file/bot{os.getenv('TOKEN')}/{file_path}") as f:
        html = f.read()
    return psycopg2.Binary(html)
```

and then I try to save to the DB binary object which is returned above. But I got this error:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "<"
LINE 1: ...photo) VALUES (297850814, 'sdf', '09.04.2023', 7, <psycopg2....
```

So how to save a pic to the DB properly?

function which saves data to the DB:

```
def insert(table: str, column_values: Dict) -> None:
    columns = ', '.join(column_values.keys())
    values = tuple(column_values.values())
    q = f'''INSERT INTO {table} ({columns}) VALUES {values}'''
    cursor.execute(q)
    connection.commit()
```

update: I tried this code:

```
file_info = await bot.get_file(message.photo[len(message.photo) - 1].file_id)
data["photo"] = (await bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)).read()
```

and got this error:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: ...c*@\x03\t+\xa0^U\x16n\x83)%\x005:F\xc9!H\x85\x1e\'(.\x1a\x90...
```

How to solve it?

Comment: What made you think this would work in the first place?  Are you following some documentation or tutorial?

Comment: @jjanes yes, I followed this article first:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/save-a-image-file-on-a-postgres-database-python/
and then I found this question and followed it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67733841/how-to-save-photo-from-telegram-bot-aiogram-to-postgresql-database/67734071#67734071

Comment: geeksforgeeks is a crapshow of popups, but it looks like you are supposed to pass the object to execute(), not interpolate it into a string using python's interpolation.  (which you shouldn't do anyway, just for security reasons).